# What’s causing my truck to jerk and rpms to go up and gown

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, truck

Okay so I have a 1996 Chevy 1500 pickup. When I’m going down the highway and get to 45mph or so my rpm will start to jump up and down and the truck starts to jerk. My speedometer also will drop and go all over and it makes a loud whine. I just put a new transmission with torque converter thinking it was that. But the problem still accounts. I’ve read somewhere it could be the alternator? Causing a short or something? Not sure. Wanted to get some thoughts

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!